# Inverted Standard Least-Squares Regression (ISR) in python

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels, least-squares

Hi I just wanted to perform Inverted least square regression

```
Y -> m *x + c
```

Is there any package or function is already available in python for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by `inverted least squares regression` you mean a regression that minimizes the horizontal rather than vertical distance between the line of best fit and the data. If this is the case, you can simply run a regression of `x` on `y` and then set `m* = 1/m` and `a*=-a/m`. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# DATA
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape((-1,1))
y = 0.5*x + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=x.shape)

# INVERTED LINEAR REGRESSION
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(y,x)
m = 1/model.coef_[0][0]
a = -model.intercept_/model.coef_[0][0]

# PLOT
plt.scatter(x,y, color='r', s=12, alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(x, m*x + a)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time. But Is the model fit in this example is correct? it seems like the distribution of data points kind of away from the line on the lower part. (I am totally not an expert )

Comment: Good eyes. The intercept wasn't correct originally.  Fixed now.

Comment: Is there any summary option available in this one just like in the `statsmodel`? To check the `R^2`

Answer (score 1):

you could try `statsmodels` it has a few regression algorithms, if it doesn't have what you're looking for check the implementations for the others and use it to implement yours

link: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html